# nuget not resolving dependency using what specified in nuget package for Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, nuget, nuspec

### Background:

I have created a class library for .net core (targetting `v2.2`), and I have a .net core application as well (targetting `v2.2`).

I am trying to export the library as nuget package and install it in my application.
Here is the dependencies for my library

[image: MyLib dependencies]

I am able to export it as nuget package and for now I am storing it in local nuget repo.
But when I try to install this library package in my application it's not getting installed due to package version conflict for `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`. Here's package manager console output.

[image: PackageManagerConsoleOutput]

### Issue:

I have specified the exact version for  `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` i.e. `[2.2.0]` as we could confirm that in the screenshot showing dependency for my library, then why it's getting resolved to version `3.0.0`?
How could I resolve this issue?

### Details about the environment:

- NuGet product used (Package Manager Console): Package Manager Console Host Version `5.3.1.6268`
- VS version (if appropriate): Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version `16.3.8`
- OS version (i.e. win10 v1607 (14393.321)): Windows 10 Enterprise Version: `1809`

Comment: l have created a package just as what you did and then install it in a initial net core 2.2 application and found nothing was wrong. l guess that you have install other nuget packages which depends on the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 3.0`. Please check it. Besides, if possible, please share the nuspec file(if you use), csproj file or other nuget packages if you used.

Comment: I think you need to clean the nuget cache before your install that package if you've installed that package with different content before! Cause there's one copy of your package is stored in nuget cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How could I resolve this issue?

To resolve the strange behavior in your side, you should [clean the nuget cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) before installing that package in your current project.

(To make sure the cache is cleaned up, I suggest you go `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages` to check if there exists `Com.lib` folder within the `Packages` folder)

> I have specified the exact version for Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
>   i.e. [2.2.0] as we could confirm that in the screenshot showing
>   dependency for my library, then why it's getting resolved to version
>   3.0.0?

I think the one(Com.Mylib) you want to install is not the first one you pack. I mean that you may actually build and pack several different Com.Mylib package with different content. And all of their names is `Com.lib.1.0.0.nupkg`.

Nuget stores all nuget cache in `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages`. So if I once install one PackageA in any project. The cache of PackageA is stored there. And if I open a new project trying to install the PackageA with same version(1.0.0), it **actually** installs the one from cache. So we will meet this strange behavior:

[image]

Nuget can recognize the Com.lib package depends on other 2.2.0 packages. But when it tries to install that package, it finds the package has existed in cache. Then he tries to install the one from cache, and I guess content of the one in cache is different from your latest one, then the issue occurs.

**Suggestions:**

1.When developing locally, use project reference instead of Nuget packages.

2.If you need to test the nuget package every time after packing, please make sure the package version has increased.(1.0.0=>1.0.1=>1.0.3... or beta-1.0.12, preview-xxx)

3.If you have special reason do use same version 1.0.0, please `clean the cache` to avoid previous cache affects current project.

Hope all above helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Lance Li-MSFT, deleting the nuget cache resolved the issue.